# Printing in blocks

Tags: perl, printing, printf, block

I want to print the results in two blocks (`idA` and `idB` are various genes, `$level` goes from 1 to 3)

```
open(TGFILE, "> $ofile2") || die("### ERROR ### Cannot open dot file: $ofile2\n");
printf TGFILE "'%s'\t'%s'\n", $idA, $idB;
printf TGFILE "//NODECLASS\t'%s'\t'level'\t'$level'\n", $idA;
```

it gives me the results of genes interacting in a file:

```
'SNRNP200'  'SNRNP200'
//NODECLASS 'SNRNP200'  'level' '1'
'SNRNP200'  'RNU6ATAC'
//NODECLASS 'RNU6ATAC'  'level' '1'
'RNU6ATAC'  'YBX1'
//NODECLASS 'YBX1'  'level' '1'
...
...
```

but I want to have it like this in two blocks in the output file because there are thousands of genes and can't do it manually:

```
'SNRNP200'  'SNRNP200'
'SNRNP200'  'RNU6ATAC'
'RNU6ATAC'  'YBX1'
//NODECLASS 'SNRNP200'  'level' '1'
//NODECLASS 'RNU6ATAC'  'level' '1'
//NODECLASS 'YBX1'  'level' '1'
```

Comment: how big would the data be? You could simply use 2 arrays which you could print step by step if the system would let you.

Comment: If it is only in the thousands, you can use `sprintf` on the second lines, store the strings in arrays and print them in order once your done with the file. Of course this requires that you can put half your file into memory and will fail on extremely memory limited machines or files of many gigabyte. edit: Oh yeah, or you just use leeduhems answer, that is probably the best and most fail-safe approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could print them to two different files, and combine these two files later.